# Why do we always represent only the hydrogen evolution?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

In corrosion of aluminium or magnesium for example, we have the anodic reaction which is the dissolution of the metal but for the cathodic reaction we only represent the hydrogen evolution.
How about the reduction of oxygen gas and water?
Why don't we mention these reaction and we focus only on hydrogen evolution?

Comment: There is (almost) no oxygen gas around there, just water. As for the reduction of water, guess what happens and what gas evolves as a result?